# Develop a custom count using an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I'm trying to populate an Array given another one with custom values. For instance, if my base is `[2,3,1]` the Array should look like this:

```
0,0,0
0,0,1
0,1,0
0,1,1
0,2,0
0,2,1
0,3,0
0,3,1
1,0,0 and so on...
```

The loop should finish when I get to `[2,3,1]`. I've made several changes to my code so it may be worse than it previously was.

```
max=0;  
while (!(power.containsAll(listPot))){
        while ((index<=listPot.get(pos))){ //Iterating the first digit
            power.set(pos, index); //Updating the value
            index++; //Increasing up to the limit found on listPot
        }
        index=0; //Reset the counter to put into the Array
        if(max<limit){ //max would be the position of the next digit
            max++;
        }
        if(power.get(max)<listPot.get(pos)){ //If next digit is < limit
            index++; //move the index forward
            power.set(max, index); //Increase the next digit
            while (pos>=0){ //Removing the previous digits, like from 199 to 200
                power.set(pos, 0);
                pos--;
            }
            index=0;
        }
        else { //I increase max position again and proceed like above
            pos=max;
            max++;
            while (pos>=0){ //Removing previous digits
                power.set(pos, 0);
                pos--;
            }
            index++; //Increasing the value to input
            power.set(max, index);
        }
        index=0; //Reset the counters
        pos=0;
    }
```

The main loop iterates while the arrays are different. I initialized the new one with the same length with all zeros. The other one is the target one.

**EDIT:** I'm trying to iterate values with custom limits in each position of the array. I'll use the array in each cycle to load a separated array with divisors of a given number. I provide to the method an array with the prime factors, and another with the powers of each factor.

For 900 the result is [2,3,5] for the prime factors and [2,2,2] for the power. This particular case should be a base 3 iteration since all elements are 2. This is not possible for all cases, so I'm trying to do something more flexible.

My issue comes when I move to the next position of the array, so I'm looking for help with the usage of the variables to properly loop through the values I get from the number.

Comment: can you please tell us what are you trying to achieve? your question is hard to understand

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I don't get it: what's that array you're trying to build`?

Comment: could you add the problem statement at top, so we have a chance to figure out what to do?

Comment: you are trying to do something like `if base == [2,3,1] then return [ 0,0,0 0,0,1 0,1,0 0,1,1 0,2,0 0,2,1 0,3,0 0,3,1 1,0,0]' ?? Sure not! You should not only explain the result but what it means or how it should be archived. Could you write a program if I only tell you that given 2 and 2 it should result in 4? There is no way you would know that I want the power function (2 ^ 2) and not the addition or even the multiplication...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'll edit the post with additional info.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger could you check my question again? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to increment the values in an array up to given limits, kind of some permutations. I suggest to divide the problem like:

```
calculate(new int[] {2, 3, 1});  // example


private static void calculate(int[] limits) {
    int counters[] = new int[limits.length];
    do {
        something(counters);
    } while (increment(counters, limits));
}

private static void something(int[] counters) {
    // do whatever should be done with the counters
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counters));
}

private static boolean increment(int[] counters, int[] limits) {
    // index for counter to increment, starting at the last one
    for (int i = counters.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        counters[i] += 1;

        // if the counter is within the limits, return true
        if (counters[i] <= limits[i])
            return true;

        // if counted past limit, reset to zero and continue 
        // with previous counter (loop)
        counters[i] = 0;
    }

    // if the first counter exceeded the limit, we are done
    return false;
}
```

where `calculate` is the entry point/main loop, `something` is doing what should be done each interaction (just printing here), and `increment` increments the array, returning false if at the end

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you for the help.